# How does one cite an interview conducted in sign language (ASL) using MLA format?

Tags: citations, language, mla

One of my students is conducting a research project on how being deaf affects one's likelihood of getting a job. Her parents are both deaf, and she is fluent in ASL. She wants to interview other acquaintances on their experience with gaining and maintaining employment in order to supplement her traditional research on the topic.

My thought was to treat it as an interview and include a note as if it was translated from another language (which it technically is).

Thoughts?

Comment: How would you have her cite it if she were interviewing them in English?  Is a record of the conversation being made (like a recording or transcript), or is she just working from notes and memory?

Comment: What do you mean by "technically"?

Answer (score 3):

You cite sources. You do not cite your data. You can append the full data to the publication or publish it online. In a scientific or scholarly publication, the method of data collection must be described, as well as the resulting data set.

(The method must comply with current standards in your field, of course, and if you apply methods from a different field, such as transcribing sign language, which does not have the same syntactic structure as spoken or written English, you must give sources for the methods you apply and argue for their use, as readers will not be familiar with what you are doing.)

What "data" is depends on the field of study. In your case the interviews are the data.